# Is there an OR function in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, web-analytics

I want to see a hits on pages on my website, and to get a look at complete hits, I can't look at individual pages separately. However, I can only search for `AND` functions. The `AND` makes it so that both are required.

Is there a mechanism for an `OR` function in Google Analytics, so that I can have either requirements?
[image]

This is from `Content > Site Content > All Pages`
Then I do `advanced query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps it would help if you better explain how to reach the point where you are at...because at face value that looks like a custom segment and you *can* use `OR` operations in them: [image]

**edited to add**:  At the top of the report just under the report title (it should be a big bold **Pages** header for your report), click on the `Advanced Segments` button.  You will see a screen with `default segments` on the left, and `custom segments` on the right. Just under and to the right of the `custom segment` text area is a `+New Custom Segment` button.  Click that button and it will bring up the menu shown in my screenshot above.

Comment: @Caryon I just added it above, but I go to  Content > Site Content > All Pages; Then I do advanced query to get to my image.  What steps are for your image?

Comment: @SnowboardBruin  Edited my answer to include steps to get to my image!